# Safari 5 on Windows 8 inverts all text-elements on SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, safari, d3.js

I have an application in which I create SVG-charts with D3.js (Version 3). This works fine in all browsers except for Safari (Version 5.1.7 on Windows 8.1). Safari shows all text-elements upside down with the y-value inverted.

Another fact is that when I save the generated SVG-code and then load it in Safari, everything is fine.

Does anyone know if this is a known problem/bug? And is there a way to easily fix this or should I add some special code in my JS-file for Safari.

To specify my problem I have added two screenshots, on top is how it is shown in Safari and below how it should be shown.

Safari:

[Safari http://www.leonhooijer.nl/Safari.png](http://www.leonhooijer.nl/Safari.png)

Other browsers:

[Should Be http://www.leonhooijer.nl/Chrome.png](http://www.leonhooijer.nl/Chrome.png)

Also here is the generated SVG-code:

```
<svg width="473" height="357" viewBox="0 0 530 400" perserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid" class="chart" style="margin-left:8.5px">
<g class="arc" transform="translate(265,200)">
    <path d="M9.490699242123424e-15,-155A155,155 0 0,1 87.92411853567042,127.64932189293204L0,0Z" class="first_group"></path>
    <path d="M87.92411853567042,127.64932189293204A155,155 0 0,1 -79.92927812076182,132.80177144561705L0,0Z" class="second_group"></path>
    <path d="M-79.92927812076182,132.80177144561705A155,155 0 0,1 -152.74492900530055,26.34362661376928L0,0Z" class="third_group"></path>
    <path d="M-152.74492900530055,26.34362661376928A155,155 0 0,1 -140.44015392173435,-65.58630319235537L0,0Z" class="fourth_group"></path>
    <path d="M-140.44015392173435,-65.58630319235537A155,155 0 0,1 -97.60019756608148,-120.41262988184363L0,0Z" class="fifth_group"></path>
    <path d="M-97.60019756608148,-120.41262988184363A155,155 0 0,1 -64.84357257048977,-140.78462663336373L0,0Z" class="sixth_group"></path>
    <path d="M-64.84357257048977,-140.78462663336373A155,155 0 0,1 -2.847209772637027e-14,-155L0,0Z" class="seventh_group"></path>
</g>
<g class="lbls" transform="translate(265,200)">
    <line x1="0" x2="0" y1="-158" y2="-170" class="first_group" transform="rotate(72.72057342529297)"></line>
    <line x1="0" x2="0" y1="-158" y2="-170" class="second_group" transform="rotate(178.24179077148438)scale(1,1)"></line>
    <line x1="0" x2="0" y1="-158" y2="-170" class="third_group" transform="rotate(235.62850952148438)scale(1,1)"></line>
    <line x1="0" x2="0" y1="-158" y2="-170" class="fourth_group" transform="rotate(-82.37631225585939)"></line>
    <line x1="0" x2="0" y1="-158" y2="-170" class="fifth_group" transform="rotate(-51.996795654296896)scale(0.9999999999999999,0.9999999999999999)"></line>
    <line x1="0" x2="0" y1="-158" y2="-170" class="sixth_group" transform="rotate(-31.87829589843751)"></line>
    <line x1="0" x2="0" y1="-158" y2="-170" class="seventh_group" transform="rotate(-12.365081787109395)"></line>
    <text transform="translate(170.92128845655768,-53.16872344104387)" class="value first_group" dy="-10" text-anchor="beginning">40.4%</text>
    <text transform="translate(5.492020303912323,178.91572796426092)" class="value second_group" dy="2" text-anchor="beginning">18.2%</text>
    <text transform="translate(-147.74560637652337,101.05560744675884)" class="value third_group" dy="2" text-anchor="end">13.7%</text>
    <text transform="translate(-177.41777441646744,-23.74728028864517)" class="value fourth_group" dy="-10" text-anchor="end">9.7%</text>
    <text transform="translate(-141.0477648281888,-110.21128815585067)" class="value fifth_group" dy="-10" text-anchor="end">7.2%</text>
    <text transform="translate(-94.53290710464508,-152.00174168194437)" class="value sixth_group" dy="-10" text-anchor="end">4.0%</text>
    <text transform="translate(-38.331103265489965,-174.84772381260885)" class="value seventh_group" dy="-10" text-anchor="end">6.9%</text>
    <text transform="translate(170.92128845655768,-53.16872344104387)" class="units first_group" dy="8" text-anchor="beginning">0</text>
    <text transform="translate(5.492020303912323,178.91572796426092)" class="units second_group" dy="20" text-anchor="beginning">1</text>
    <text transform="translate(-147.74560637652337,101.05560744675884)" class="units third_group" dy="20" text-anchor="end">2</text>
    <text transform="translate(-177.41777441646744,-23.74728028864517)" class="units fourth_group" dy="8" text-anchor="end">3</text>
    <text transform="translate(-141.0477648281888,-110.21128815585067)" class="units fifth_group" dy="8" text-anchor="end">4</text>
    <text transform="translate(-94.53290710464508,-152.00174168194437)" class="units sixth_group" dy="8" text-anchor="end">5</text>
    <text transform="translate(-38.331103265489965,-174.84772381260885)" class="units seventh_group" dy="8" text-anchor="end">6+</text>
</g>
```

**Edit:**

I found at [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-fragment) website that the viewbox is not supported in Safari. Could this cause the problem? I do use the viewbox to handle page resizing.

Comment: Does this happen only in Safari on Windows?

Comment: I do not know, since I don't have a Mac-device to test it on.

Comment: This displays fine on MacOSX. Safari/Windows is an end-of-life product, there is no need to support it any more.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to this as it was happening to me too.

```
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

That was set in the body tag of my CSS, and removing that, fixed it.
I think it has a problem rendering antialiased text.

So if you aren't using that CSS command, try just disabling font smoothing by using:

```
    -webkit-font-smoothing: none;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I added this line to my CSS. It doesn't seem to help though. I might mention that I use a viewbox and when I resize to a smaller size the text is shown correctly.

Comment: This did help me with *Windows Safari 5* inverting all <text> elements in an SVG and repositioning them on page reload|any redraw on it.

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge its because the CSS3 has been used for transition in D3 for whic you need WEBkit as suggested in W3C..

```
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp
```

Hence this problem occuring.

There are lots of issues regarding this translate.

```
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/WqGkpYKpXfc
```

I too still couldn't find a proper way to solve it.

Comment: According to the W3Schools article, Chrome would also need the -webkit-prefix, but Chrome renders everthing fine. 
Also I'd rather not expand al my JS-code with special -webkit-prefixes, cause this would make it much larger (because I also use transitions).

Comment: This is my idea regarding this problem,it has been handled inside D3 upto certain level.. even adding Webkit wont solve the problem.. it solve only for Chrome as The Safari later versions need another param extra to be appended.. you may put into the D3 repo as issue you faced.. check this question and the accepted answer for an idea  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211261/css3-animation-not-working-in-safari

Comment: As mentioned in the question I use Safari 5.1.7 on Windows 8.1. I will place the issue on the D3 repo.