# CSS Animation working on Chrome but not on Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, animation, safari

the code below works fine on Chrome, but not on Safari:

```
@-webkit-keyframes jiggle {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(-.5deg);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(1deg);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }

}

.animated_container {
    -webkit-animation-name: jiggle1;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 40%;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.21s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.43s;
    animation-name: jiggle1;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    transform-origin: 50% 40%;

}
```

I created an example in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2obx0rvL/

What am I missing here ? Thx!

Comment: that not all css is available for all browsers?

Comment: No only the relevant part of the css is displayed here... The full css is in the fiddle.

Comment: What I meant was: Just because it works in one browser, another may render it differently. I can't test it on my pc atm, but try [this](http://htmlcsstricks.com/demo/61-css3-animation-effects/css3-wobble-animation.html)

Comment: Your wobble animation works fine on both browsers, but I would have expected the same for my animation. The fact is that both webkit based browsers should interpret it more or less the same way. I don't ask Safari to render it exactly like Chrome, but at least to attempt to render it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're not setting the full range on the transform percentage. Safari requires that you specify the 100% endpoint. See this related answer: [CSS3 animation not working in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211261/css3-animation-not-working-in-safari)

Comment: Many thanks Duncan, that's it ! I updated the fiddle here for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/2obx0rvL/4/