# @keyframe animation on safari

Tags: css, safari, webkit

I'm trying to do a very simple rotation animation using keyframes. My animation is not showing up in Safari 6 using retina macbook pro  and ipad mini. What's weird is that it does work inside jfiddle iframe window.

```
 <html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
   <style type='text/css'>
     body {padding: 25px; background: black;}
     .one {
       -webkit-animation: all 6s linear infinite;
       background: red;
     }

     @-webkit-keyframes all
     {
       0%   {-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);}
       100%    {-webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);}
     }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="one">test</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Doesn't work on retina macbook pro and ipad mini using safari

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211261/css3-animation-not-working-in-safari refer this

Comment: That link doesn't help me very much