# Css animation not running on iPad Safari

Tags: css, ipad, animation, safari

I have a small problem that my client would not accept.

The top slider animation on the iPad on safari is running only on 2 slides. It's a custom slider animation created by me using CSS3 animation and jQuery class changes.
It's working well on chrome iPad and on all other browsers, just not on safari on mobile.

Here is the site: http://co.built.digital/

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the CSS3 Keyframes isn't supported in Safari, you need to use the whole percentage. See this question for more details: ([CSS3 animation not working in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211261/css3-animation-not-working-in-safari))

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9431098/3891896)