# CSS Animation for Scrolling Text Doesn't Work on Safari

Tags: html, css, animation, safari

I'm trying to have a scrolling marquee of sorts across the top of my webpage. I'm not using the  tag as it is not supported by Safari. However, even with using CSS Animation, it doesn't seem to work for Safari either. Here's my code:

```
<h3>Upcoming Shows:...</h3>
```

This is what I have in my style sheet:

```css
h3 {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 /* Starting position */
 -moz-transform:translateX(100%);
 -webkit-transform:translateX(100%);    
 transform:translateX(100%);
 /* Apply animation to this element */  
 -moz-animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
 animation: example1 15s linear infinite;
}
/* Move it (define the animation) */
@-moz-keyframes example1 {
 0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
 100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes example1 {
 0%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
 100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@keyframes example1 {
 0%   { 
 -moz-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 transform: translateX(100%);       
 }
 100% { 
 -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 transform: translateX(-100%); 
 }
}
```

Comment: [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211261/css3-animation-not-working-in-safari) I this is what you are trying to do

Comment: In my Safari, your code works. http://plnkr.co/cJKNktwDovBI6lhNLBR4