# How to have an HTML text element loop on itself?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, sass

I'm working on some front-end stuff and learning react. Currently, I'm building a background component that takes in an arbitrary string as a prop and builds a set of spans filled with that string. [Here's a brief JSFiddle mockup to better illustrate what I'm doing](https://jsfiddle.net/n0vjgb9p/51/).

My intent is to have rows of this text scroll horizontally in the background indefinitely for *aesthetics*. I've made solid progress so far, but currently I'm facing an issue related to how the the text animates.

```
  @keyframes animatePos {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(+100%);
    }
  }
```

With this, the text moves all the way to the other side of the view, which is great! Except, the animation doesn't repeat until it's completely finished, so there ends up being a lot of whitespace, which I'm looking to remove. I've read through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51505446/css-scrolling-text-loop), but the solution involves transforming the text into an svg, which I don't think would be a good direction to go in due to how I want this text to be dynamic.

I'm a bit lost at where to go from here. My first thought was to push additional entries onto the array once the span moves a certain amount, but that is definitely not a very scalable solution. Again, I'm new to react so I'm not sure what it's capable of in this situation. Any suggestions on what direction to take this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to make a marquee? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847392/pure-css-continuous-horizontal-text-scroll-without-break

Comment: @evolutionxbox In essence, yes. However, the marquee functions like what I mentioned above, where it waits for the text to reach the end of the page before repeating. I'd like the text to begin repeating as soon as it reaches the end of the page, making a full loop with no whitespace.

Comment: You’ll probably need to duplicate the text for it to wrap like that.

Answer (score 0):

I played with your stuff, very kool.

I don't really know much about Marquee, but seems it has something to do with your text.

If i changed the text to `text: "abc"`. It seems to work with the way you want.