# CSS animation fails to load on Safari

Tags: html, css

My goal is to make a CSS animation load properly on Safari. Currently the animation works on Chrome and Brave but it doesn't work correctly on my iPhone's Safari browser. Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/plutownium/3ne7dwvp/9/

If you open the page and click "run" in the top left corner, you will see the animation play as it's supposed to if you load it on Chrome. What I am looking for is for the animation to "slide in" from the left and fill up the background div. It does this properly on -- as far as I know -- all browsers except Safari.

I am using `@-webkit-keyframes` specifically for the animation... so it's not that I'm missing those...

I tried changing my webkit keyframes indicators from `to` and `from` to `0%, 100%` as in [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211261/css3-animation-not-working-in-safari/17529003):

```css
@-webkit-keyframes hideBlack {
    0% {
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    }
    100% {
        clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%);
    }
}
```

but still the animation does not work. I just see a grey box.

To add more examples of what doesn't work, view the top 2 answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211261/css3-animation-not-working-in-safari). Quote, "In Safari when you use Keyframes you need to use the whole percentage" did not make the "reveal" and "hideBlack" animations work in my phone's safari browser.

I tried following [this page's advice](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/safari-does-not-accept-webkit-keyframes-and-animations/), " Safari does not read trough the shorthand method for describing the animation [...] It needs to be described more detailed with its separate properties listed" but it doesn't load on Safari either (just the grey box again): https://jsfiddle.net/plutownium/3ne7dwvp/15/

*note the second jsfiddle link is chronologically *after* the previous link

I have also added the following lines in my css classes since starting my venture:

```css
-webkit-animation-name: hideBlack;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.75s;

&

-webkit-animation-name: reveal;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.75s;
```

but still the animation does not play. There's just a bunch of grey filling the `div`s where I expect to see yellow/white sliding in from the side w/ black text.

Again my *most recent* minimum reproducible example is available on jsfiddle through this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/plutownium/3ne7dwvp/15

I am beginning to grow suspicious that I did not implement one of the solutions correctly. Let me know in the comments if I messed up making my fiddle...

Comment: According to caniuse, safari does not support animations for the clip path property full stop: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_clip-path_animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this table [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path), This clip-path property does not support by all modern browser.

When you see something like this problem, You should check this property or value in caniuse.com.

[CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/) is an extremely useful tool for quickly visualizing which frontend technologies are compatible with which browsers. ... At a glance, you can see which major browser supports the technology in question, notes, resources, known issues, and more.