# Safari animation background-position have braking animate

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, css-animations, css-transitions

I makes css keyframes for parallax animate. In Chrome, Opera I have smooth transition.

In Safari I have very braking animate.

```
@keyframes animatedParallelogram {
    0 {
        background-position: 1000px 0px;
        transform: translateX(-100%) scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        background-position: -1000px 0px;
        transform: translateX(100%) scale(1.1);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes animatedParallelogram {
    0 {
        background-position: 1000px 0px;
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%) scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        background-position: -1000px 0px;
        -moz-transform: translateX(100%) scale(1.1);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatedParallelogram {
    0 {
        background-position: 1000px 0px;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        background-position: -1000px 0px;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%) scale(1.1);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes animatedParallelogram {
    0 {
        background-position: 1000px 0px;
        -o-transform: translateX(-100%) scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        background-position: -1000px 0px;
        -o-transform: translateX(100%) scale(1.1);
    }
}
```

You can open my example and try to slide down: [OPEN EXAMPLE](http://encore.mediaz.info/)

Comment: try to add % to 0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS3 animation not working in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211261/css3-animation-not-working-in-safari)

Comment: When I use %, background-position doesn't move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Safari have braking animate, if used CSS animate «background-position» and other transform animation together.