# Issues delaying SCSS animation on Safari and iOS devices

Tags: css, ios, animation, safari, css-animations

I'm new to Apple dev and am having trouble delaying a CSS animation on Safari. When attempting to delay, as well as delaying the marquee2 animation, the width the animation takes up increases, and as a result `marquee2` overtakes `marquee`. The behaviour can be seen [here](https://www.sableradio.live) (the issue is visible only on Safari and iPhones).

There is likely a line of `-webkit-animation` I am missing somewhere, and I have so far tried:

- adding `-webkit-animation: marquee 12s linear infinite;` to `marquee`
- adding a slight delay as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40028240/12421922)
- breaking the animation into separate chunks as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17529003/12421922)

The project in full is [here](https://github.com/kaz-212/sable-front) if you're interested. Thank you in advance!

```
  <div class="ticker-wrap">
    <div class="ticker">
      <p class="marquee">
        <span>Hello1</span>
      </p>
      <p class="marquee marquee2">
        <span>Hello2</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
.ticker-wrap {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  direction: rtl;

  .marquee {
    line-height: 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
  }

  .marquee span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 120%;
    animation: marquee 12s linear infinite;
  }

  .marquee2 span {
    animation-delay: 6s;
  }

  @keyframes marquee {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
      transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
      transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes marquee {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    }
  }
}

  .ticker > * {
    direction: ltr;
  }
```