# CSS Animation does only work in Firefox and Chrome, but not on Apple Devices (Safari?)

Tags: html, css, ios, browser, css-animations

I have made a little animation counting numbers that works completely fine in Firefox and Chrome browsers, but not in default browser of Apple devices (Safari?):

```css
div::after {
  font: 800 40px system-ui;
  content: counter(count);
  animation: counter 5s linear forwards;
  counter-reset: count 0;
}

@keyframes counter {
   0% { counter-increment: count 0;    }
  10% { counter-increment: count 8;    }
  20% { counter-increment: count 16;   }
  30% { counter-increment: count 32;   }
  40% { counter-increment: count 64;   }
  50% { counter-increment: count 128;  }
  60% { counter-increment: count 256;  }
  70% { counter-increment: count 512;  }
  80% { counter-increment: count 1024; }
  90% { counter-increment: count 2048; }
 100% { counter-increment: count 4000; }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

How can I make this work also on Apple devices?

Maybe add some `-webkit-animation` or `@-webkit-keyframes` somewhere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS3 animation not working in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211261/css3-animation-not-working-in-safari)

Comment: Yes, you got it right. You have to update the styles with webkit prefix. You can check browser compatibility [here](https://caniuse.com/)

Comment: @JackBennett: Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately the linked answer does not help, because I am already using percentages up to 100 %.

Comment: @Ms.Tamil: Thanks for your comment! So I have to double-insert all code including the `-webkit`-prefixes?

Comment: Looks like I missed that answer, sorry. I agree with the other comment by Ms. Tamil, though - check browser compatibility and ensure your code works with safari that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `webkits` for your keyframes:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes counter {
   0% { -webkit-counter-increment: count 0;    }
  10% { -webkit-counter-increment: count 8;    }
  20% { -webkit-counter-increment: count 16;   }
  30% { -webkit-counter-increment: count 32;   }
  40% { -webkit-counter-increment: count 64;   }
  50% { -webkit-counter-increment: count 128;  }
  60% { -webkit-counter-increment: count 256;  }
  70% { -webkit-counter-increment: count 512;  }
  80% { -webkit-counter-increment: count 1024; }
  90% { -webkit-counter-increment: count 2048; }
 100% { -webkit-counter-increment: count 4000; }
}

@keyframes counter {
   0% { counter-increment: count 0;    }
  10% { counter-increment: count 8;    }
  20% { counter-increment: count 16;   }
  30% { counter-increment: count 32;   }
  40% { counter-increment: count 64;   }
  50% { counter-increment: count 128;  }
  60% { counter-increment: count 256;  }
  70% { counter-increment: count 512;  }
  80% { counter-increment: count 1024; }
  90% { counter-increment: count 2048; }
 100% { counter-increment: count 4000; }
}


div::after {
  font: 800 40px system-ui;
  content: counter(count);
  animation: counter 5s linear forwards;
  counter-reset: count 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Also take a look at [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! :-) So this does also work on Apple devices? Unfortunately I don't have any for testing here...

Comment: @Dave For me it works for Firefox, Chrome and Safari :) . So i guess so

Comment: This won't work on Safari as it will pick up the second set of keyframes just like all the other browsers.

Comment: @Dave also take a look at https://caniuse.com/ . With the website you can see if which elements are supported in all browsers or if you might need a `webkit`. Or it is supported. Here are also two pictures how you can find something like that: 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wHWi.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrpRu.png

Comment: @AHaworth it works for me though. Which version are you using?

Comment: Actually, I don't think Safari needs the webkit - apologies. The second set of keyframes should work on Safari like anything else, but it doesn't for me (iPad IOS 14.7.1)

Comment: @AHaworth okayy